# Programmatically create coupon code in Stripe

Tags: java, ruby, rest, stripe-payments

I need to create over a 1000 coupon codes in my Stripe account so that customers can redeem the discount at my site. I don't want to do this manually through the dashboard or else I'll go crazy.

I have not been able to find instructions in STRIPE documentation to create coupon codes programmatically or through a REST client.

Does anyone know if this is possible using the Stripe api. Could you provide an example if you gotten this to work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's definitely possible using the [Create Coupon](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#create_coupon) API. You'd be able to use their [Java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java) library to create all those in a loop. Here's a basic example taken from the documentation that creates a 25% off coupon for 3 months:

```
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_XXX";

Map<String, Object> couponParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
couponParams.put("percent_off", 25);
couponParams.put("duration", "repeating");
couponParams.put("duration_in_months", 3);
couponParams.put("id", "25OFF");

Coupon.create(couponParams);
```

Comment: @Worthy7 not sure what specifically you mean with your comments. The docs are still here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/coupons/create

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant that they mention in the docs about creating a loop to solve this - my bad

Comment: Ah no sorry they don't have docs for this today.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a coupon using Stripe Ruby api like this:

```
      require "stripe"

      Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2"
       => "sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2" 

         Stripe::Coupon.create(
             :percent_off => 25,
             :duration => 'repeating',
             :duration_in_months => 3,
             :id => '25008OFF'
         )
       => #<Stripe::Coupon:0x3ff55618447c id=25008OFF> JSON: {
        "id": "25008OFF",
        "created": 1435205613,
        "percent_off": 25,
        "amount_off": null,
        "currency": null,
        "object": "coupon",
        "livemode": false,
        "duration": "repeating",
        "redeem_by": null,
        "max_redemptions": null,
        "times_redeemed": 0,
        "duration_in_months": 3,
        "valid": true,
        "metadata": {}
      }
```